# Disabling screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, stock-android, android-emulator, sim-unlocking

Suppose my android phone is locked by any locking method like password , pin, or pattern. 
Suppose my mobile is not a rooted phone , neither have custom recovery installed.

Is there is any way to unlock it with the stock recovery or anything like that ?

Without WIPE USER DATA . I don't want the data to be removed.

Also suppose no Google accounts help is available.

Comment: And suppose the bootloader is still locked? Then chances are close to zero – unless you've got enough Forensics & technical knowledge to deal with the chips directly. And even that won't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

there's some ways to do it, but 90% of it will wipe User data. If you did OEM on, you can save your data on backup then wipe the phone by fastboot mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to know some methods used by the cops to crack the phones (locked) where the data should not be deleted. I need any method like writing some payload for Trojan and injecting in it using some method t want to know.If you know please answer me.. Thanks

Comment: depending of your device, have 'ByPass' softs that use ADB/fasboot the unlock the phone. suppose if the device is a Motorola, so I should have 'Motodevice Manager' and 'ADB fastboot'. this method you need connect the phone on a PC. the softs you need you'll found on site's XDA looking for your device model. I hope it now help you.